# MSI: installer for installers

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I need to create installer using MSI whose aim would be to invoke correct installer based on region (read from env. variables) of the user. That is, this installer is supposed to have 3 files(which are installers itself) one for US, one for Europe and one for Asia.

Now the point is that this Main installer never gets installed, but what it does is that it invokes the correct installer (Asia, Europe or US), so its installer that eventually gets installed.

Is it possible to do this. Any work arounds would be more than welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called a custom EXE bootstrapper. It's a simple EXE application which determines the machine environment and launches the appropriate installer. Optionally you can pack all your installers into it and extract them at runtime.

You can write the EXE yourself or try to find an existing solution.

Comment: Appreciate your help. I forgot to mention that my main installer has to be nothing but an msi only. I am not allowed to invoke an exe to do the same.